# How can I change the color of these arrows?

Tags: css

I have this page:

http://test2.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

Here you will find your slider (Revelution Slider),plugin for Wordpress.

I want to change the color of these arrows.

http://i62.tinypic.com/6tlrp1.jpg

I tried to inspect the code where reference is made to this color code but unfortunately I have not found.

Perhaps it is something very simple but fail to figure out how to solve this problem.

You can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `wp-content/themes/mix/css/template.css` **Line 10904** and change `background-color` property to this:

```
.tparrows:hover{
    background-color:blue
}
```

It will change color when you move your mouse to the arrow.

But still you will not get perfect blue color because there is `box-shadow` property is given to `wp-content/themes/mix/css/template.css` **Line 10904** so if you want perfect blue color then change it also :

```
.tparrows:hover{
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0, 1) 0s;
    box-shadow: 0px -50px 0px 0px blue inset;
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

**Change the Style of the Navigation Arrows via StyleSheet in Revolution Slider**

You can add the following lines to your Style Sheet :

- Open up the Slider Settings
- Expand the Navigation Section
- Change Navigation Arrows to “solo”
- Change Style to “round”
- Open up any of your Stylesheets (i.e.  Appearance / Editor)
- Change the Style of the following Classes:

  `.tparrows
  .tparrows.default
  .tp-rightarrow
  .tp-leftarrow`

For example :

```
.tparrows {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
width: 40px !important;
height: 40px !important;
top: auto !important;
}

.tparrows.default:after {
color: #999;
font-size: 25px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
width:40px;
line-height:40px;
text-align:center;
font-weight: 300;
top:0px; left:0px;
font-family: 'fontello';
}

.tp-rightarrow.tparrows.default:after { content: 'e75e'; }
.tp-leftarrow.tparrows.default:after { content: 'e75d'; }
```

For more details, check it out here : http://www.themepunch.com/faq/change-the-navigation-arrow-in-the-slider/

Hope it helps you.